# Symfony 3.3 - Hwioauth bundle, How to check user login is facebook user or google user

Tags: symfony, hwioauthbundle

When login by hwioauthbundle i want to check user login is facebook user or google user. Thank for reading!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: check exist $response->getProfilePicture(). if has is google, null is facebook.

Answer (score 0):

In the user provider you should have an loadUserByOAuthUserResponse function.
In this function, you can find user type as shown below:

```
public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response)
{
    switch (get_class($response->getResourceOwner())) {
        case 'HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\ResourceOwner\GoogleResourceOwner':
            // google user
            break;
        case 'HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\ResourceOwner\FacebookResourceOwner':
            // facebook
            break;
```